# How to aggregate column on changing criteria in SQL (multiple SUMIFS)

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

Consider the following simplified example:

Table **JobTitles**

```
| PersonID | JobTitle | StartDate | EndDate |
|----------|----------|-----------|---------|
| A        | A1       | 1         | 5       |
| A        | A2       | 6         | 10      |
| A        | A3       | 11        | 15      |
| B        | B1       | 2         | 4       |
| B        | B2       | 5         | 7       |
| B        | B3       | 8         | 11      |
| C        | C1       | 5         | 12      |
| C        | C2       | 13        | 14      |
| C        | C3       | 15        | 18      |
```

Table **Transactions**:

```
| PersonID | TransDate | Amt |
|----------|-----------|-----|
| A        | 2         | 5   |
| A        | 3         | 10  |
| A        | 12        | 5   |
| A        | 12        | 10  |
| B        | 3         | 5   |
| B        | 3         | 10  |
| B        | 10        | 5   |
| C        | 16        | 10  |
| C        | 17        | 5   |
| C        | 17        | 10  |
| C        | 17        | 5   |
```

**Desired Output**:

```
| PersonID | JobTitle | StartDate | EndDate | Amt |
|----------|----------|-----------|---------|-----|
| A        | A1       | 1         | 5       | 15  |
| A        | A2       | 6         | 10      | 0   |
| A        | A3       | 11        | 15      | 15  |
| B        | B1       | 2         | 4       | 15  |
| B        | B2       | 5         | 7       | 0   |
| B        | B3       | 8         | 11      | 5   |
| C        | C1       | 5         | 12      | 0   |
| C        | C2       | 13        | 14      | 0   |
| C        | C3       | 15        | 18      | 30  |
```

---

To me this is **JobTitles** LEFT OUTER JOIN **Transactions** with some type of moving criteria for the `TransDate` -- that is, I want to `SUM` Transaction.Amt if Transactions.TransDate is between JobTitles.StartDate and JobTitles.EndDate per each PersonID.

Feels like some type of partition or window function, but my SQL skills are not strong enough to create an elegant solution.  In Excel, this equates to:

`SUMIFS(Transaction[Amt], JobTitles[PersonID], Results[@[PersonID]], Transactions[TransDate], ">" & Results[@[StartDate]], Transactions[TransDate], "<=" & Results[@[EndDate]])`

Moreover, I want to be able to perform this same logic over several flavors of Transaction tables.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: If your database supports the CASE statement, you can almost certainly use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic query is:

```
select jt.PersonID, jt.JobTitle, jt.StartDate, jt.EndDate, coalesce(sum(amt), 0) as amt
from JobTitles jt left join
     Transactions t
     on jt.PersonId = t.PersonId and
        t.TransDate between jt.StartDate and jt.EndDate
group by jt.PersonID, jt.JobTitle, jt.StartDate, jt.EndDate;
```